# Facebook React.js :: Pass data for Client Side rendering

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to create my first web application using React.js.

I wish to have React perform client side rendering, however the pages rendered are controlled by data held on a server hosted database.

How should i pass this data to React?

Do i have to pre populate each html page on the server side with a json representation of my data?

Or can React access my database from the client side directly (or using a RESTful API call)?

**UPDATE: 001**

All the examples i can find have REACT.js installed on node.js.
Can i use REACT.js on Apache Tomcat™, IBM Websphere Liberty Profile, Jetty?

Comment: You can embed it into the page or use an ajax call, whichever suits you better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two approaches you mentioned could both work, [this blog post](https://benzhang.xyz/reactjs/isomorphic/2015/05/02/isomorphic-webapp-react-express-coffee/) gives an example of **server-side** rendering and embedding props in the rendered HTML.

**EDIT:**

In response to your edit, I'd say that React is a Javascript framework, and it naturally should be deployed on a javascript server such as [Node](https://nodejs.org/). If you'd rather not use Node, you can for sure write client-only scripts that uses AJAX to request data from the API server. [Here is a great example from Facebook](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/initial-ajax.html).

A snippet of it:

```
componentDidMount: function() {
  $.get(this.props.source, function(result) {
    var lastGist = result[0];
    if (this.isMounted()) {
      this.setState({
        username: lastGist.owner.login,
        lastGistUrl: lastGist.html_url
      });
    }
  }.bind(this));
}
```

Above code populates the `state` object with data from the server once the component is mounted.

Comment: Ben, what about loading the data the first time( without Ajax call)? I'm not sure how I'd get it working with JSX compilation...

Comment: Yes, embed the data as an encoded JSON string directly inside the html using a `<script>` tag. Then in React, get the contents of that tag and convert it back into a JavaScript object.